# How to intercept 500 internal server error in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an endpoint whose error response has to be intercepted and logged or transformed. I included a fault sequence and i'm logging all the possible errors. But i'm unable to get the 500 Internal Server Error intercepted. Can some one please help me in this?

Please see below.

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <address uri="https://<Hostname/WebServiceName>" format="soap11">
  <suspendOnFailure>
     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
  </suspendOnFailure>
  <markForSuspension>
     <errorCodes>500</errorCodes>
     <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
     <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
  </markForSuspension>
  <timeout>
     <duration>100</duration>
     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
  </timeout>
  <enableSec policy="conf:/repository/esb/policies/Sign-UT-Policy.xml"/>
</address>
</endpoint>
```

Error log 
     `TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Set-Cookie: CSQA9IBCOOKIE=R2172309488; path=/[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 14:21:08 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "1f[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "{"getMyClsScheduleResponse":""}[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-06 09:21:08,790] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}`

As shown above, i see a 500 Internal Server error in the logs, but its not sent to fault sequence.

Any ideas would help..

Thanks
Kranthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learnt over the past few months that we need to use the following parameter in the API/Proxy to send the http error code back to the fault sequence.

```
<inSequence>
        <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</inSequence>
```

The parameter `<responseAction>`in the endpoint timeout setting is not the name of your fault sequence, it just mentions whether the control should be sent to the fault sequence or be discarded.

```
<timeout>
<duration>100</duration>
<responseAction>fault</responseAction>
```

The name of the fault sequence where it has to be routed is mentioned in the proxy

```
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StudentDashboardAcademics" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target faultSequence="StudashFault">
<endpoint key="conf:/repository/esb/endpoints/CSIB_Dynamic.xml"/>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="Accept" expression="$trp:Accept" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        </inSequence>
```

Good luck everyone with coding ...

Best Wishes
Kranthi

Answer (score 0):

Add your fault sequence to the proxy and see whether you can catch the error or not